# Retrieve url of uploaded file from google form

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-forms

I have found an extremely good google script for a google form that allows me to retrieve the answers of a google form in a spreadsheet along with the "getEditResponseUrl()" that will help me build a database that can be modified through the google form.

However, I am struggling in getting the url of an "upload file question". The question where the user is supposed to upload a file is the fourth one "facture".

The answer I get in my spreadsheet is only "[Ljava.lang.Object;@508c8b8b" but not the file.

Any idea how to make this work so that I get the url of the file that was uploaded by the user ?

Thank you and Kind regards

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("spreadsheeturl");  // to be customised
var responseSheet = "Database";  // to be customised

function submitFormFunc(e) {
var items = e.response.getItemResponses();
  var responses={};
  for(var i = 0; i< items.length; i++) {
  responses[items[i].getItem().getTitle()]=items[i].getResponse();
   }

  var responseRow = [];
  responseRow.push(e.response.getTimestamp().toString());
  responseRow.push(e.response.getId());
  responseRow.push(responses["Challenge"]);  // to be customised
  responseRow.push(responses["Client"]); 
  responseRow.push(responses["Date"]); 
  responseRow.push(responses["Facture"]); 
 // to be customised
  // add as many as needed

  responseRow.push(FormApp.getActiveForm().getResponse(e.response.getId()).getEditResponseUrl());

  var isNewItem = alreadyExist(ss,e.response.getId());
  if(isNewItem<0){
    ss.getSheetByName(responseSheet).appendRow(responseRow);
  }
  else{
    ss.getSheetByName(responseSheet).getRange(isNewItem+2, 1, 1, 6).setValues([responseRow]);
  }
}

function alreadyExist(ss,id){
  var ids = ss.getSheetByName(responseSheet).getRange("B2:B").getValues();
  for(var i=0; i< ids.length; i++){
    if(ids[i][0]===id){
      return(i);
    }
  }
  return(-1);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a snippet from the [Form Notifications add-on](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/email-notifications-for-f/acknfdkglemcidajjmehljifccmflhkm) that converts the uploaded file ids into Google Drive URLs and concatenates the result in case of multiple uploads.

```
 var urls = answer.toString().split(",").map(function(f) {
                return "https://drive.google.com/open?id=" + f;
             }).join(", ");
```